# How to do a direct cash flow statement given a stock ticker

Tags: accounting, cash-flow, financial-statements

Does anyone know of a good step by step process on how to generate a direct cash flow statement for a publicly traded company? I was able to look up their financial info (given their stock ticker) on google finance, but I cannot get all the net cash flow items to match up with the indirect cash flow. For instance, the net income and operations matches indirect, but not the investing and financing. Is there better place to look company info besides yahoo or google finance that would have the information needed to complete the direct cash flow statement?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For US equities, Edgar Online is where companies post their government filings to the SEC. On Google Finance, you would look at the "SEC filings" link on the page, and then find their 10K and 10Q documents, where that information is listed and already calculated.

Many companies also have these same documents posted on their Investor Relations web pages.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Any recommendations if the 10k or 10q doesn't exist? Think the company started trading publicly early this year, but trying to do direct cash flow statement for last year.

Comment: @James read the prospectus then.